# Error when trying to compare matching words from an arraylist when searching through words with more than 2 matching letters

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, cycle

`ActionListener` gives error when `builtwordcheck` length is longer than 2 letters. The point of the `ActionListener` when pressed is to print out all words in a list (word list array file) that match a word (`builtwordcheck`) and are longer than that word. I'm not sure if there is needed further context as to how the word is built, but simply it's letters are added one by one through clicks through String word = word + [letter]

Example:
cat should print out cats, caterpillar, ...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:1512)
    at MainGame$HintAL.actionPerformed(MainGame.java:117)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

---

```
class HintAL implements ActionListener{
    String Arrayword;
    boolean match;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        match = true;
        Arrayword = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < wordlist.size(); i++) {
            Arrayword = wordlist.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < builtwordcheck.length(); j++) {
                if (Arrayword.charAt(j) != builtwordcheck.charAt(j) || Arrayword.length() <= builtwordcheck.length() /* add condition for having reached the end of the array word (.length) */){
                    match = false;
                }
            }
            if (match == true){
                System.out.println(Arrayword);
            }
            match = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `Arrayword.length() == builtwordcheck.length()`?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand correctly. but not always, in fact the program should avoid that case like in ` Arrayword.length() <= builtwordcheck.length()` at the first if. it should just give me the ones matching larger than the builtwordcheck

Comment: Seems to me, they have different lengths. In the absence of the complete knowledge of the related code snippet, this is a wild guess I could make, which can cause the **StringIndexOutOfBoundsException**. Moreover, this question has nothing to do with "swing", it would be appropriate to **remove swing tag** from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of your code is throwing `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```java
if (Arrayword.charAt(j) != builtwordcheck.charAt(j) || Arrayword.length() <= builtwordcheck.length() /* add condition for having reached the end of the array word (.length) */){
```

This is because the value of `j` is **not** less than the length of `Arrayword`.

The simplest fix for your existing code is simply to swap the order in the `if` condition, i.e.

```java
if (Arrayword.length() <= builtwordcheck.length() || Arrayword.charAt(j) != builtwordcheck.charAt(j)) {
```

A better solution would be to call method [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)).

```java
if (Arrayword.contains(builtwordcheck)) {
```

An even better solution – if you are using at least Java 8 – is to use [streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html).

```java
class HintAL implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        wordlist.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.contains(builtwordcheck))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Note that the last line in the above code uses [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) (which were also added in Java 8).

Also note that it is recommended to adhere to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Also, I think it is appropriate for me to recommend to you the book [Java by Comparison](https://java.by-comparison.com/)